# Обработка исключения в асинхронном методе

Tags: c#, async-await

Всем привет, помогите ответить на вопрос:

Пример с неправильной асинхрой, объяснить почему неправильно.
// будет ли поймано исключение, выброшенное в методе OtherMethodAsync? Любое или не всякое?

```
public Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    try
    {
        return OtherMethodAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть очень хорошая подборка как лучше писать асинхронный код. Он может быть не самым оптимальным, зато позволит избежать 99% проблем.  Ваш случай тоже покрывается.
https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-asyncawait-over-directly-returning-task

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения вызывающего кода (`MyMethodAsync`) метод `OtherMethodAsync` - это просто метод, возвращающий `Task`

Асинхронность в виде async/await - это детали реализации `OtherMethodAsync`.
Если `OtherMethodAsync` выбросит исключение при вызове - оно будет поймано. "При вызове" в этом случае означает "до возврата Task".

В случае async использования `async`/`await` для реализации `OtherMethodAsync - все исключения внутри будут перехвачены и возвращены в виде объекта` Task`, так что если вы просто возвращаете Task выше по цепочке вызовов - исключение вы не поймаете, оно будет выброшено только при первой попытке сделать await или получить результат еще каким-то способом.

[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

> When an exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that exception is captured and placed on the Task object.

Так что общий ответ - зависит от кода в `OtherMethodAsync`. Хотите ловить все - сделайте `MyMethodAsync` async, и напишите в нем await.

Comment: *"В случае async методов это обычно означает "выбросит исключение до первого await""* - не, не означает, см. комментарий под другим ответом

Comment: @PavelMayorov если честно, не понял что не так с комментарием под другим ответом. Там же вроде просто кидается исключение до await, нет?

Comment: @PavelMayorov а, дошло. Ну, если кто-то сможет оформить ответ с полным описанием без оговорок «обычно» - я не против. В вопросе вообще ничего про async нет :)